# Creating the savings and cheque accounts

Tags: c#

You have been approached by ABC bank to develop an application that will help in managing their customers. The bank has two different types of accounts that a customer can open:
a.  Check Account, a customer with a checking account typically receives interest, maintains a minimum balance, and pays service charges if the balance falls below the minimum balance. The following operations on this account are also required: set interest rate, retrieve interest rate, set minimum balance, retrieve minimum balance, set service charges, retrieve service charges, post interest, verify if the balance is less than the minimum balance, write a check, withdraw/deposit.
b.  Savings Account, a customer with a savings account typically receives interest, makes deposits, and withdraws money. The following operations on this account are also required: set interest rate, retrieve interest rate, post interest, withdraw/deposit
c.  The two accounts have the following things in common, they store the account number and the balance they also provide the following common operations: set the account number, retrieve the account number, retrieve the balance, deposit and withdraw money, and print account information.
d.  Every account has an account holder who should have at least one account. Use your own discretion on the information you might want to include here.

Develop an application for above scenario. Use Windows Form to develop the application. Marks will be allocated for the correct use of   encapsulation, inheritance and polymorphism etc. Proper naming standards must be adhered to. You are also required to submit a small test document as part of your submission where you test the functionality of the application using a list of data objects. Test at least three 3 parts of your functionality e.g., adding an account holder and creating an account for them or making a deposit or checking balance e.tc. do screen shots and include them in a word document (These details should be as detailed as possible and step by step.). Make sure to make your application as user friendly as possible i.e., the user should not be left to assume how they are supposed to operate.

Comment: Posting your assignment requirements and waiting for us to do it for you is not how this site works. This is a place for getting help with specific programming problems rather than a place for cheating on your homework. I suggest that you spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of posting your homework/assignment/project, please instead refine your question to be about topics you do not understand or have issues with and then post the relevant information in a new question